# Combination and permutation Discrete math problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

100 players from each of the 3 teams form a line. For each player (except first and last), the two neighboring players must be from 2 teams different than his team. The first and last player in the line must have his neighboring student from a team different than his team. How may ways are there to form such a line of 300 players?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Other people will be more inclined to help you if you show what you've attempted so far. :)

Comment: I dont know how to even start :/

Answer (score 1):

First let’s count the possible sequences of teams. If the teams are represented by the numbers $0,1$, and $2$, we want to count the strings that contain exactly $100$ of each of the three digits and that have the property that every string of three consecutive digits contains one of each digit.

Suppose that the first two digits are $01$; then the next digit has to be $2$, so the first three digits are $012$. The three-digit string that starts with $12$ has to contain all three digits, so the fourth digit has to be $0$, and the string must start $0120$. The three-digit string that starts with $20$ has to contain all three digits, so the fifth digit must be $1$, the string must begin $01201$, and we’re more or less back where we started. It should be clear (and can be proved by induction) that if the string begins $01$, it must consist be

$$\underbrace{\underbrace{012}\underbrace{012}\underbrace{012}\ldots\underbrace{012}}_{100\text{ triplets}}\;.$$

In fact the string is completely determined by its first two digits; how many possible strings are there?

Once one of the possible strings has been chosen, the $100$ members of Team $0$ can fill their $100$ spots in the line in $100!$ different ways. The same is true for the members of Team $1$ and for the members of Team $2$. Put the pieces together, and you’ll have the total number of allowable lineups.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly there are 6 possible strings  and for each of these there are 3(100!) ways for all of the team members to line up . Therefore because there is 6 possible strings, the total number of ways to form the line would be 3x6x(100!).

Comment: @user2871765: Not quite. There are $6$ possible strings, but the rearrangements of the members of Team $k$ are independent of those of Team $\ell$ for $k\ne\ell$: each of the $100!$ arrangements of Team $0$ can be combined with any of the $100!$ arrangements of Team $1$ and any of the $100!$ arrangements of Team $2$, for a total of not $3\cdot100!$, but rather ... ?

Comment: (100!)^3 for one string and 6(100!)^3 account for all of the possible strings?

Comment: @user2871765: There you go! Yes, that’s exactly right.